# undefined symbol: gdk_visual_get_depth on Red-hat Linux as I tried to run sqldeveloper 19.1.0

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed Oracle DB 12.2.0 and SQLDeveloper 19.1.0 on a VMware with a Red-hat Linux OS.
All installations were successful and Oracle DB is working fine but every time I tried to launch the sqldeveloper interface, It launches successfully then closes again abruptly then gives me the following message.

**Oracle SQL Developer Copyright (c) 2005, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.**

/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_212-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_212-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libglassgtk2.so:undefined symbol: gdk_visual_get_depth

How do I stop it from closing abruptly?

Comment: Make sure you're on Oracle Java JDK, and update the gtk to v3 or latest and greatest

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8.212. I have also updated the gtk version to 3.28.4 and it's still closing abruptly. Do I have to uninstall and reinstall the SQLdeveloper?